# Three.js - Images managing - Recommendations

Tags: javascript, image, optimization, three.js

I have a project which looks actually like this:

[image]

The idea is: a generic room which increases its height, depending on the number of pictures the user loads.

It works... but as I load more than 100 pictures, it starts to hit performance pretty badly.
This is my very first Three.js project, so I'm definitely a newbie.

I've been searching for some tips & tricks about optimization and I would like to have your opinion.

In order to respect the images dimensions, I do a Promise.all to fetch all images before the World initialization.
Then I'm building the mesh according to the image width/height ratio with a PlaneBufferGeometry.

[image]

Apparently, it is recommended to load textures with power of two size (https://discoverthreejs.com/tips-and-tricks/ -> Textures part).
Should I resize all my images so that their width & height are powers of two and the ratio is the closest to the original?
How would you manage such a thing since the original images have many different sizes?

EDIT:
This how is create the drawing object :

```javascript
export class Drawing {
    constructor(texture) {        
        
        const imgW = Math.floor(texture.image.naturalWidth / 20);
        const imgH = Math.floor(texture.image.naturalHeight / 20);        
        const material = new MeshBasicMaterial({
            color: 0xffffff,
            map: texture
        });      
        material.color.convertSRGBToLinear();  
        this.mesh = new Mesh(new PlaneBufferGeometry(imgW, imgH), material);
    }
```

In the end, I just the mesh to the scene.

Comment: if you are using the latest three.js then you dont need to have textures with a power of two size.

Comment: after you resize the images do you keep the original around? that could fill memory pretty fast.

Comment: I'm not sure, I've edited the post to show you how I create a drawing. Am I supposed to "dispose" textures after creating meshes ?

Comment: No, it looks like you are using the `imgW` and `imgH` only for constructing the plane geometry. Your textures are the original size (1000+ pixels) so yes you are overloading your memory. You are not supposed to `dispose` the textures ... just resize them to a tenth (for example) of their original size at load time.

Comment: A good video uploaded to youtube about debugging memory which may be useful. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YDU_3WdfkxA

Answer (score 1):

You could generate mipmaps which load different (power) quality images at corresponding scales. However, an even greater performance bottleneck is clearly resource management. You should approach image loading as a feedback (lazy) loop, instead of a monumental one-shot function. Perhaps you parse the metadata for 1000's of images, but defacto load new textures dynamically as the camera position approaches breakpoints. For example at y=100, load images 200-300. You may also contend with grid masonry and fog to improve the lightbox experience. Definitely reduce images exceeding a reasonable dimension, using canvas or something appropriate. Avoid the "walled garden" approach and the burden will be on features, not quantity.